# Python @classmethod - is 'cls' just a coding style requirement?

Tags: python, class-method

Where is the difference between this:

```
class Dummyclass:
    value = 4
    def dummymethod(value):
        Dummyclass.value = value

Dummyclass.dummymethod(31)
```

and:

```
class Dummyclass:
    value = 4
    @classmethod
    def dummymethod(cls, value):
        cls.value = value

Dummyclass.dummymethod(31)
```

Except there is a `@classmethod`?

Comment: Everything works by calling the Classname.classmethodname.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are:

- Without the decorator you can call `DummyClass.dummymethod(42)`, but not `DummyClass().dummymethod(42)` (because the latter returns a bound method which tries to pass `self` as the first argument). With the decorator both will behave the same.
- If you inherit this class and call `dummymethod` on a subclass, without decorator you'll always manipulate `Dummyclass` only; while with decorator you'll receive the subclass as argument instead and can thus implement proper inheritance.